# how can I build this method in a more concise way?

Tags: ruby, coding-style, activesupport

```
def self.sort(_sort_items, _collection)
  return _collection unless _sort_items

  _collection.sort! do |first_item, second_item|
    side_one = []
    side_two = []

    _sort_items.each do |sort_item|
      a = first_item.send(sort_item.item_name)
      b = second_item.send(sort_item.item_name)

      if sort_item.descending
        side_one << b
        side_two << a
      else
        side_one << a
        side_two << b
      end
    end

    side_one <=> side_two
  end
end
```

**I want to write this method in a more concise/stylish way**

### Sort method explanation:

The `#sort` method take a collection and order by multiple attributes.

If I have a `@collection` like this:

[image: source collection]

and `@sort_items`:

```
@sort_items.add_item(:gender, true)
@sort_items.add_item(:age, false)
```

If I perform:

```
MyClass.sort(@sort_items, @collection)
```

I will get:

[image: sorted collection]

The same collection ordered by `gender desc` first and then by `age asc`.

> I'm using pure ruby but including [Active Support](https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/master/activesupport)

Comment: When you say `sort_item.descendant`, do you mean to say `sort_item.descending`?

Comment: oh! yes, my poor English...

Comment: if `arr` is an array containing two-element arrays whose element are  `age` (a `Fixnum`) and gender (a string), you can sort sort on gender descending and then age ascending (to break ties) as follows: `arr.sort_by { |a,g| [g,-a] }.reverse`.

Comment: ...or `arr.sort_by { |a,g| [(g=='M') ? 'F' : 'M', a] }`.

Comment: In my case `arr` can contain two or more items

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for concision and style, your code actually looks pretty good.  It's well-organized and readable.

I do see a way to optimize for performance:  If I'm understanding the method correctly, you should only have to go to the next level of `_sort_items` if you have a tie (i.e. both items being compared are the same: "F" vs "F").  So you could have an early return as soon as the 2 items are different:

```
_sort_items.each do |sort_item|
  a = first_item.send(sort_item.item_name)
  b = second_item.send(sort_item.item_name)

  if sort_item.descending
    side_one << b
    side_two << a
  else
    side_one << a
    side_two << b
  end

  return side_one <=> side_two if a != b
end
```

My only other suggestion would be to watch out for methods getting too long.  This one is over 20 lines, and you should think about separating some logic into a separate method.  Maybe something like this:

```
_sort_items.each do |sort_item|
  a = first_item.send(sort_item.item_name)
  b = second_item.send(sort_item.item_name)

  add_to_sides(a, b, side_one, side_two)
  return side_one <=> side_two if a != b
end

.
.
.
def add_to_sides(a, b, side_one, side_two)
  .
  .
  .
end
```